# What is a good way to clone a database with only certain tables?

Tags: mysql

My situation:

I have a MySQL database, DB1, which is fed new data every hour via a PERL script. I want to create a second database, DB2, which is a copy of DB1 except it only has one of the tables that DB1 has. DB2 must be updated either every hour or whenever DB1 is updated (whichever is the most simple to implement).

What would be a good method of doing this? I'm mostly looking for simple ideas that won't take too long to implement, but I'm open to any and all ideas you might have.

Additional information:
- DB2 will be used to connect to a Tableau dashboard. 
- DB1 has terrible performance and will be scrapped in the near future.

Comment: If both the databases are going to be on the same server, then you can utilize Triggers. Else, if different servers, then setup Master Slave replication (Master being DB1, and Slave being DB2). You can then do [Table level Replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16825/160363)

Comment: "Terrible performance"?  Missing a suitable composite index?  How big is the table?  Consider `INSERT INTO db2.t SELECT * FROM db1.t` if not too big.

Comment: @Rick there is 7GB worth of data. I would have to run that command about 3 times an hour so for my usecase unfortunately not suitable

Comment: yes agree with @MadhurBhaiya. set up table level replication. But full replication is still better.